# How can Gower distance be transformed into a kernel function?

Tags: statistics, kernel

I would like to assign weights to some results based on Gower distance. The Kernel function has good qualities so that I consider transforming Gower distance to a kernel. But I do not know how.

Is transformation s=exp(γ∗d^2) feasible (d is Gower distance)?
Do you have any other thoughts? And it would be better if you could send the references.

Thank you soooo much!